# Anchor back to the main page changes this main page into a dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, reload

I have two pages: Page A and Page B, built with jquery mobile. On Page A, I have a popup dialog, in which there is a menu option displaying Page B when I click on it. On Page B there is a back button leading me back to Page A when I click on it.

Here is my problem. If the users of my app decide for some reason to reload Page B and then push the back button on Page B after reloading it, the page A will change its appearance from full screen into a dialog view. I realized that this strange behavior only occurs, a) after reloading Page B and b) when calling Page B from a popup menu on Page A, as described above.

Is there a way to tell jquery mobile not to change the appearance of Page A, no matter whether or not Page B gets reloaded? Of course, as I mentioned above, calling Page B directly (and not through a popup menu) would also solve my problem, but I would like to keep my popup menu on Page A and I'm looking for a better solution.

Here is my code causing this problem:

Page A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h2>Page A</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href='#popupMenu' data-rel='popup' data-transition='slideup' class='ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a'>Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role='popup' id='popupMenu' data-theme='b'>
        <ul data-role='listview' id='listview' data-inset='true' style='min-width:210px;'>
            <li data-role='list-divider'>Choose an action</li>
            <li><a href='pageb.html' data-rel='page'>Page B</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Page B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Page B</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline' data-rel="back">Back</a>       
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if you add `data-history=false` to your popup?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I tried but it did not solve the problem. I also noticed another symptom: When I reload Page B and push the back button, jqm for some reason adds "#&ui-state=dialog" to the url of Page A.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `data-history="false"` to your popup, like this:

```
<div data-role='popup' id='popupMenu' data-history="false" data-theme='b'>
    <ul data-role='listview' id='listview' data-inset='true' style='min-width:210px;'>
        <li data-role='list-divider'>Choose an action</li>
        <li><a href='pageb.html' data-rel='page'>Page B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will prevent JQM to add the `Popup` to the history stack.